# Main data drive giving I/O errors

Tags: ext4, io

My main data drive is throwing up all sorts of weird I/O Errors:

```
(tail of dmesg output)
[ 7081.267852] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[ 7081.267856] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 7081.267860] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 36 c4 48 d0 00 00 08 00
[ 7081.267870] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 918833360
[ 7081.270431] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[ 7081.270435] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 7081.270439] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 36 c4 48 d0 00 00 08 00
[ 7081.270449] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 918833360
[ 7081.468662] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[ 7081.468667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 7081.468671] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 36 c4 48 d0 00 00 08 00
[ 7081.468681] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 918833360
saad@Home-Server:~$ tail /var/log/syslog
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.270431] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.270435] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.270439] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 36 c4 48 d0 00 00 08 00
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.270449] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 918833360
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.468662] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.468667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.468671] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 36 c4 48 d0 00 00 08 00
Mar 15 14:23:19 Home-Server kernel: [ 7081.468681] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 918833360
```

Is the drive dead? Or is it a mbr corruption issue?

Answer (score 0):

It not that likely to be MBR this far in - either a drive problem or random corruption, back it up quick if you haven't already!

Then you'll want to run fsck & badblocks over it:

```
sudo -i
fsck -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 # or whatever partition it is..
e2fsck -c /dev/sdb
```

The man page for badblocks recommends to do it this way, not directly. If it's got SMART monitoring then look at the logs & run tests for that as well.